# Responding to incoming SMS

Tags: sms

I am new to Twilio and tasked with evaluating whether to switch from our current service which is CDyne.

We have an application that uses SMS to interact with clients on behalf of staff using two-way SMS. The app automatically launches SMSs at certain trigger events and based upon the responses from clients decides what to do next - including asking further questions of the client. The SMS gateway I use currently allows me to include a reference id in outgoing messages. This id is returned when someone replies to the message. This makes it dead easy to look up everything related to the incoming message and form a decision and reply. Twilio does not seem to have anything similar. In fact, it does not even return the SMS ID of the original message which seems to make it a pain to determine the relation. I understand you could potentially look up the FROM and TO and trace it back, but with multiple phone numbers being used for the same client (staff can send messages directly too using a different phone number and there are several numbers being used for mass text messages), this is potentially (very) hazardous.

Question 1: Is there any (good) solution to this issue in Twilio, and
Question 2: If not, why not??? (It seems pretty obvious and simple to include a reference to the initiating SMS in the reply)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many features that CDYNE offers at no cost to their customers.

To my knowledge, Twilio doesn't offer this feature.

For additional information on SMS Notify!'s additional free features, [check out CDYNE's wiki.](http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/SMS_Notify!#API_Features)